# Debugging a for loop that crashes

Tags: python

I have a Python script that loads a CSV file of data and then runs functions on each line using a for loop.  It all works great apart from consistently at item number 247 it exits.  No error message, I just get returned to a command prompt.

I have tried entering debug statement to narrow down what is happening bu I am still no clearer as there is no error message.

Is there a way to run Windows Python is some sort of verbose mode so I can watch it running and see why my loop is stopping?

Comment: Are you sure it's not 257? It's one of magic numbers in CPython implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Comment: try posting few lines from your csv and code sample too

Comment: you can check out `pdb` the python debugger

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module, with a selective if condition to invoke it for row containing item 247 only. Something like below, which will enter the interactive debug mode for the case when its not working:

```
for line in csvfile:
    if row_item == 247:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    # regular processing here
```

From there, you can `step` into the function to understand what is not working.